# Not able to get Labels from Promtail static_configs

Tags: grafana, loki

I'm using the latest promtail and loki and trying to use your static_configs example.. but I'm not getting the labels pushed to Loki..   all I see below

```
Discovered labels
__address
__path
job
```

I do not see labels of facility and hostname am I doing something wrong ?

here is my promtail

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: C:\loki\tmp\promtail\positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: rfc5424
  pipeline_stages:
    # Assuming the logs are in RFC5424 format, use the regex to extract the hostname and facility
    - regex:
        expression: '.*?(\d+)\s\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+.*'
        output:
          source_labels: [facility, hostname]
    # Map the extracted facility number to a facility name
    - labels:
        facility: "${1}"
        hostname: "${2}"
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: rfc5424
      __path__: C:\logs\rfc5424\*log
```

My Log format is

```
1 2003-10-11T22:14:15.003Z mymachine.example.com evntslog - ID47 [exampleSDID@32473 iut="3" eventSource="Application" eventID="1011"] BOMAn application event log entry...
```